# Removing the mock locations provider issue

Tags: android, gps

I am using test GPS provider in my app, and when I am trying clean up the test provider after the usage.

The issue is that my GPS stops working after that, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
if (locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)!=null){
    locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false);
    locationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

I know that there is a [newer API](http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html), but I prefer to use the old one.